# Не видит маршрут по ссылке laravel. Route [reset_password] not defined

Tags: php, laravel

программисты, помогите, у меня каким то магическим образом не выводится на экран нужная страница, выдавая ошибку `Route [reset_password] not defined.` В чем может заключаться проблема?

страница, которая не выводится login_form.blade.php:

```
<form method='POST' action="{{route('login')}}">
    @csrf
    <h1>Вход в систему</h1>
    <ul>
        <li class="li"><label>
                <input class="input" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email"/>
            </label></li>
        <li class="li"><label>
                <input class="input" type="text" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password"/>
            </label></li>
        <div>
            <a href="{{route('reset_password')}}" accesskey="1" title="">Сбросить пароль</a>
        </div>
    </ul>
    <button class="button" type="submit">Войти в систему</button>
</form>
```

Необходимая строка файла web.php, которая магическим образом не отрабатывается вообще

```
Route::get('/resetPassword','AuthController@resetPassword')->name('reset_password');
```

Контроллер AuthController.php

```
public function resetPassword()
    {
        return view('reset_password');
    }
```

Файл reset_password.blade так же присутствует и содержит в себе полноценную страничку с формой

Comment: Не рендерится форма или в самой форме ошибка, что роут route('reset_password') не найден?

Comment: `php artisan route:clear` писали?

Comment: @Vladimir Gonchar , ваш ответ помог, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

"php artisan route:clear писали? – Vladimir Gonchar "

Спасибо, Vladimir Gonchar, мне тоже помог